# Как менять некоторые части html при сборке шаблона?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rigger

Собираю проект при помощи `gulp'a`, допустим я делаю многостраничник, я использую плагин `gulp-rigger`, его суть в том, что он позволяет соединять какие-либо части шаблона, тоже самое можно делать и с помощью `PHP`. Допустим у нас есть повторяющаяся шапка, мы можем ее подключить ко всем страницам и после сборки, этот кусок просто вставится в основной `html` документ. Проблема в том, что если у меня в шапке навигация, и надо подсвечивать определенный активный пункт на странице, как это решить? То есть у меня будет класс который определяет активную часть, и я должен задавать его пунктам меню в зависимости от страницы.

Comment: Если уж лепить костыли...
Можно на основе URL назначать тому или иному элементу класс через JS

Comment: как насчет взять другой плагин который работает и имеет документацию? (panini)

Comment: похоже, ваш плагин такого не умеет

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использовать [gulp-rigger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rigger) не самое лучшее решение. Он не поддерживается совсем. У автора последний коммит был аж в [сентябре 2015 года](https://github.com/kuzyk/gulp-rigger/commit/d1115918df42338db8d53dfedd7f7d21b206751e). На [issues](https://github.com/kuzyk/gulp-rigger/issues) он не отвечает с того же времени. Это очень старый не поддерживаемый плагин не имеющий документации.

Есть альтернатива этому плагину - [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include).
Свою задачу, вы можете решить например вот так:

src/_nav.html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="@@navAbout"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    <li class="@@navCatalog"><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
    <li class="@@navContacts"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

src/about.html

```
@@include('_nav.html', {navAbout": "active", "navCatalog": "", "navContacts": ""})
```

src/catalog.html

```
@@include('_nav.html', {navAbout": "", "navCatalog": "active", "navContacts": ""})
```

получается:

about.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

catalog.html

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li class=""><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var location = window.location.pathname; // полный путь после основного URL
            // var cur_url = '/' + location.split('/').pop(); // при необходимости оставить только последню часть пути
            $('.navba-nav li').each(function () {
                var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                if (location == link) // тут в зависимости от того что нужно location можно заменить на cur_url
                {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```